# What happens to undissolved salt during electrolysis of brine?

Tags: electrolysis, salt

Say we have a container of brine with excess NaCl in the anode, and a seperate container with just water at the cathode. Both are connected by a salt bridge. If we perform electrolysis, Sodium ions will migrate away to the cathode. Does this mean that some of the undissolved NaCl will now be able to dissolve?

Comment: Try it :-) Or simulate it with an electric circuit with very big serial resistor.

Comment: Does that mean no?

Comment: It means you should think about it long enough before asking. // The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It would prevent others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. 

Effort not shown can be considered as effort not done and such a question may be  closed.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the cathodic region contains only pure water, there will be no electrolysis. Pure water is not conducting the current. After some time, some ions will pass from the salt bridge to the cathodic region, which becomes slightly conducting. But the current will be extremely small